# How to best measure automation coverage against a system under test via reports?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, automated-tests, cucumber

How to best measure automation statistics / coverage against a system under test (From your experience)?

Brief Overview:

- Currently have over 100 tests (Feature file & scenarios) which are also tagged dependent on the type of area of the system which they are testing.
- The tests are also integrated into Jenkins which also generates reports post test execution.

Currently I am having problems measuring the number of tests created and the number of tests which need to be created against a given system which may be the front end system, backend UI system etc.

I'am aware of Extent Reports which aids the process of distinguishing different test types etc (Tags..) however just thought I would get others thoughts and opinions on the subject?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always space for judgment errors, when trying to

> measure automation statistics / coverage against a system under test

as there are no tools to (really) automate the thinking and skills of a good QA engineer. Test coverage as metric is only useful up to a point. It can help you identify gaps and where you need to spend more efforts. How do you know if 69% is poor test coverage, but 70% is good!?

In my experience and to give you more concrete answer, we have used a simple formula:

> for every acceptance criteria, you need at least:
>
> - one positive scenario
> - one negative scenario (or two, if you want to cover "system does, something that it shouldn't" and "system doesn't do, something that it should" cases)
> - destructive scenario (like malformed input)

Of course, in most cases you will need more than that, but those should be the default minimum. Now, having some numbers and mapping, you can go and create a heatmap, to show in your reports. Something, business friendly like this maybe:

[image: simple test coverage heatmap]